# amazon s3 and carrierwave random image name in bucket does not match in database

Tags: ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I'm using carrier wave, rails and amazon s3. Every time I save an image, the image shows up in s3 and I can see it in the management console with the name like this:

`https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/
uploads/images/10/888fdcfdd6f0eeea_1351389576.png`

But in the model, the name is this:

`https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/
uploads/images/10/b3ca26c2baa3b857_1351389576.png`

First off, why is the random name different? I am generating it in the uploader like so:

```
def filename
  if original_filename
    "#{SecureRandom::hex(8)}_#{Time.now.to_i}#{File.extname(original_filename).downcase}"
  end
end
```

I know it is not generating a random string every call because the wrong url in the model is consistent and saved. Somewhere in the process a new one must be getting generated to save in the model after the image name has been saved and sent to amazon s3. Strange.

Also, can I have the url match the one in terms of s3/bucket instead of bucket.s3 without using a regex? Is there an option in carrierwave or something for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by saving the filename if it was still the original filename. In the uploader, put:

```
def filename
  if original_filename && original_filename == @filename
    @filename = "#{any_string}#{File.extname(original_filename).downcase}"
  else
    @filename
  end
end
```

The issue of the sumbdomain versus the path is not actually an issue. It works with the subdomain. I.e. `https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-name/` and `https://bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com/` both work fine.

Answer (score 3):

CarrierWave by default doesn't store the URL. Instead, it generates it every time you need it.

So, every time `filename` is called it will return a different value, because of `Time.now.to_i`.

Use `created_at` column instead, or add a new column for storing the random id or the full filename.

Comment: I appreciate the tip it wasnt saved. I just needed to save it